# Click trigger Jquery looping

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

i have a problem with a piece of code, i have an input file where users can upload files, when the user select a file and try to click the same input i want to show a modal box showing a message for confirm replace and if user click accept the file browser window should come up, right now this part a got it but,

when user click the button the modal shows up but if this modal is called again it causes a loop and several file browsers windows shows up. what is wrong?

i tried using event.preventDefault(), but file browser window won't show up

```
$(".fileinput-button").click(function (event) {
    var fileupload = $(this);

    if ($(this).hasClass('change')) {
        var name = $('.change').find('span').prop("id");
        $("#documentName").html(name);
        $("#replaceConfirmation").modal('show');

        $("#replaceFile").click(function () {
            fileupload.find('input').trigger('click');

            $("#replaceConfirmation").modal('hide');
        });

    }

});
```

Comment: Do you have multiple elements with class="change"? `$('.change')` will match all of them, not just the one that was clicked on.

Comment: yes, i have multiple elements, oh, any workaround?

Comment: Use `fileupload` instead of `$('.change')`. I don't know if that's your whole problem, but it's part of it.

Comment: Also, `$("replaceConfirmation")` is wrong, I suspect it should be `$("#replaceConfirmation")`.

Comment: i changed these two lines 

if ($(this).hasClass('change')) {
        var name = $('.change').find('span').prop("id");

to this  if (fileupload.hasClass('change')) {
            var name = fileupload.find('span').prop("id");
and still the same problem.

Comment: Every time you click on one of the buttons, it adds another click handler to `#replaceFile`. So when you click on that, it does `trigger('click')` multiple times. You need to bind that click handler once at the beginning, or unbind it when it's not needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
var fileupload;

$(".fileinput-button").on('click',function (event)
{
    fileupload = $(this);
    if ($(this).hasClass('change'))
    {
        var name = $('.change').find('span').prop("id");
        $("#documentName").html(name);
        $("#replaceConfirmation").modal('show');
    }
});

$("#replaceFile").on('click',function ()
{
    fileupload.find('input').trigger('click');
    $("#replaceConfirmation").modal('hide');
});
```

Comment: thanks, i ended up doing this, taking out the second click event did the trick thanks, and sorry i'm new on this.